# Native php. Not works namespace use

Tags: php, namespaces

I`m use namespace in my project. But namespace not works.

file index.php

```
use \Folder\Aa;
Aa::test();
$test = new Aa();
```

file Folder/Aa.php

```
namespace  Folder;
class Aa
{
    static function test()
    {
        $a = 3;
        echo $a;
    }
}
```

Write me Fatal error: Class 'Folder\Aa' not found in /home/ademidko/www/first.local/index.php

I`m changes namespace in Аа.php, write "use \Folder" and other -> but not works

Comment: Works fine for me here: https://3v4l.org/rBuUu did you include/require `Folder/Aa.php` in `index.php` ?

Comment: Has `Aa.php` been required or otherwise autoloaded?

Comment: `use` solely deals with *namespaces*. It has zero to do with managing files and/or loading them.

Comment: in manual write about symbolic  link http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: You're probably misunderstanding whatever it's saying. `use` *aliases* namespace names. Perhaps that's where you get "symbolic link" from. It has nothing to do with files.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not load classes dynamically by itself. In order to you to be able to use your class your code have to look like this:

```
require_once('Folder/Aa.php');
use \Folder\Aa;
Aa::test();
$test = new Aa();
```

There are many possible ways how to make this work without manually writing `require` or `require_once`. One of them is to use composer's autoloading functionality (details can be found here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4).
You can also consider writing your own autoloader (more details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)